# How to switch images after animation?

Tags: python, oop, animation, kivy

I have a couple of questions:

1. I have animation of spinning ball which should be always on top of screen and screen should always show only half of it. I can do it but only by clicking buttom to call function which take ball to the right place. I need ball to be always in right place not only then i click the button. I tried to use **init** function but it always give me this error: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'. I also tried to use **getattr** instead of **init** but it doesn't take ball to the right place.
2. So I want click a button and ball start spins for a couple of seconds. When it stops I want ball to be another color or even another image of ball. I tried to use on_complete but I don't understand where I should use it.

My main py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class OpenScreen(Screen):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    #Trying to make __init__ function
    #def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #super(OpenScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #y = self.height
        #y1 = self.width / 2
        #self.ids.test.pos = 0, y - y1

    #Function of taking ball in the right place and spinning it
    def z(self):
        anim = Animation(angle=360, duration=0.5)
        anim += Animation(angle=360, duration=0.5)
        anim.start(self)
        y = self.height
        y1 = self.width / 2
        self.ids.test.pos = 0, y - y1
        self.ids.test.source = 'redball.png'


    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0


...screens classes...


GUI = Builder.load_file('game.kv')
class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self, screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']                
        screen_manager.current = screen_name



GameApp().run()
```

My Openscreen.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<OpenScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                source: 'bg.png'
        Image:
            id: test
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.width
            source: 'blueball.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: root.angle
                    axis: 0, 0, 1
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix
        Button:
            text: "spin"
            font_size: self.height - 29
            valign: 'middle'
            halign: 'center'
            padding: 2,2
            size_hint: .7, .1
            pos_hint:{"x":.15, "y":.585}
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            on_press:
                root.z()
....
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Try scheduling a call to set up the ball using `Clock.schedule_once()` in your `__init__()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the animation using `Clock.schedule_once()` as:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(OpenScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.z)
```

You will need to add a `dt` argument to the `z()` method and utilize the `on_complete` event as:

```
def z(self, dt):
    anim = Animation(angle=360, duration=0.5)
    anim += Animation(angle=360, duration=0.5)
    anim.bind(on_complete=self.switch_source)
    anim.start(self)
```

Then use a `switch_source()` method as:

```
def switch_source(self, *args):
    y = self.height
    y1 = self.width / 2
    self.ids.test.pos = 0, y - y1
    self.ids.test.source = 'redball.png'
```

Comment: Yes but it wasn't exectly what i wanted. So i made it like:     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OpenScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.switch_source, 0)

    def switch_source(self, *args):
        y = self.height
        y1 = self.width / 2
        self.ids.test.pos = 0, y - y1   And it worked. thank you anyway!